# PostgreSQL 9.4 create table if not exists

Tags: ddl, postgresql-9.4

I created tables on heroku using the following DDL.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Team"(
  "id" SERIAL,
  "name" varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  "description" varchar(255)
);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  "Member"(
  "id" SERIAL,
  "name" varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  "emp_number" integer NOT NULL,
  "position" varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  "team_id" integer references "Team"("id")
);
```

I got the following error:

```
    play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to execute JPA schema generation create command [CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Team"(]
  at play.db.jpa.DefaultJPAApi$JPAApiProvider.<init>(DefaultJPAApi.java:35)
  at play.db.jpa.DefaultJPAApi$JPAApiProvider.class(DefaultJPAApi.java:30)
  ...

1 error]
    at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:191) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:261) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at play.api.GlobalSettings$class.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:179) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    ...
Caused by: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to execute JPA schema generation create command [CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Team"(]
  at play.db.jpa.DefaultJPAApi$JPAApiProvider.<init>(DefaultJPAApi.java:35)
  ...

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1025) ~[com.google.inject.guice-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051) ~[com.google.inject.guice-4.0.jar:na]
    ...
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to execute JPA schema generation create command [CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Team"(]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.schemagen.GenerationTargetToDatabase.acceptCreateCommands(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:64) ~[org.hibernate.hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
    ...
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at end of input
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850) ~[org.hibernate.hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
    ...
  Position: 35
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2270) ~[org.postgresql.postgresql-9.4-1201-jdbc41.jar:9.4]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1998) ~[org.postgresql.postgresql-9.4-1201-jdbc41.jar:9.4]
    ...
```

The error is quite obvious. The SQL contains errors. I am quite new to postgres sql. At least I know the current version used by heroku supports `if not exists` syntax but I am not sure where I went wrong.

Is anybody good at PostgreSQL here?

Comment: You should really run the query directly instead of going through a web framework. This gives you actually readable errors.

Comment: Unrelated, but: you should really avoid quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble in the long run then they are worth it.

Answer (score 4):

If you had run this query directly, you would have gotten the error:

> ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "Team"

This gives you a clue that there's something missing to identify the columns in the "Team" table uniquely. You have declared that the `id`s of the tables are serials, but forgot to add primary key constraints. Adding this, will let you execute the query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Team"(
    "id" SERIAL primary key,
    ...
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  "Member"(
    "id" SERIAL primary key,
    ...
);
```